# Philips saa7134 tv tuner card not working

Tags: 11.04, xorg, video, tv-tuner, tvtime

When i run tvtime,it gives me the following output in terminal:

```
Running tvtime 1.0.2.
Reading configuration from /etc/tvtime/tvtime.xml
Reading configuration from /home/md/.tvtime/tvtime.xml
xvoutput: No XVIDEO port found which supports YUY2 images.

*** tvtime requires hardware YUY2 overlay support from your video card
*** driver.  If you are using an older NVIDIA card (TNT2), then
*** this capability is only available with their binary drivers.
*** For some ATI cards, this feature may be found in the experimental
*** GATOS drivers: http://gatos.souceforge.net/
*** If unsure, please check with your distribution to see if your
*** X driver supports hardware overlay surfaces.
```

Also i have intel 845gvsr motherboard and my tv tuner worked in past editions of ubuntu with this `options saa7134 card=3 tuner=69` option putting inside `/etc/modprobe.d/options` file.

Comment: For what it is worth, the error message you are seeing is about the capabilities exposed by the X server rather than the TV tuner card.  It would be helpful if you could update your question to mention the what video card you're using (or confirm that you're using the motherboard's video hardware), and include the output of the `xvinfo` command.

Comment: root@md-desktop:~# xvinfo
X-Video Extension version 2.2
screen #0
 no adaptors present,also i dont have any graphics card its integrated graphics on my motherboard intel845gvsr

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)